# breqn corrupts fouriernc in TL 2016

Tags: breqn, fourier

Finally, when I think I found a font I like to use, I find that `breqn` package corrupts it when using `bmatrix` and other such constructs from `amsmath`. This is so annoying.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}[Scale=0.95]
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}   %do not use this with tex4ht.  added 4/2/16

\begin{document}

\[%
\begin{bmatrix}
k_{11} & k_{12}\\
k_{21} & k_{22}%
\end{bmatrix}
-\omega_{1}^{2}%
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12}\\
m_{21} & m_{22}%
\end{bmatrix}%
\begin{Bmatrix}
\varphi_{11}\\
\varphi_{21}%
\end{Bmatrix}
=%
\begin{Bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `lualatex foo.tex`

```
  This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
   restricted system commands enabled.
```

Output is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Removing the `breqn` package, the output is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why would `breqn` break font like this? Is there a work around?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with LuaTeX or TeX4ht or `fontspec` and you don't need `luatex85` here, for sure. I can reproduce using a minimal example with pdfTeX, 2 packages + `breqn` and nothing else.

Comment: @cfr I only use lualatex, so that is why I did not try it with pdflatex. I use lualatex and tex4ht in lua mode always. Thanks for checking also. I also just changed the title and removed lualatex from it.

Comment: Using LuaLaTeX is fine, but you should minimise the example. Take out the conditional stuff. Take out `luatex85`. Take out everything you don't need to reproduce the problem. (LuaTeX is, however, beta software. So breakage is expected. Hence, it is always worth checking with another engine, if you can, if only so that you can be more specific about the problem in your question.)

Comment: Have you read `breqn`'s documentation? Especially sections 2 and 5?

Comment: `fouriernc` uses non standard math font encodings, which `breqn` (actually `flexisym`) doesn't support out of the box. It shouldn't be difficult to write a configuration file, just tedious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a somewhat more minimal example (further minimised in light of egreg's suggestion):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\begin{document}
\[\left\{\sum\right\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: not right]

As explained in sections 2 and 5 and in the documentation of the `flexisym` package beginning on page 10, `breqn` depends on `flexisym`. `flexisym` performs major surgery on the way maths is typeset.

By default, support is provided for

- `cmbase` (default)
- `mathpazo`
- `mathptmx`

If you want to use a different configuration of maths fonts, you probably need to provide a suitable setup. `breqn` suggests looking in the `.dtx` file at the existing implementations as a starting point for creating your own if your fonts are not properly supported by the default settings.

So you have to decide whether you care enough about your chosen combination of fonts and packages to write the appropriate support or, if not, which of your preferences you are least unwilling to give up.

Comment: You can reduce the example: just load `fouriernc` and `breqn`; then try a document with only `\[\left\{\sum\right\}\]` in it.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. (Please see edit if interested. Using `flexisym` is more minimal than `breqn`, but you're right about the content, of course.)