# How can I fix breqn replacing \Psi with an overbar?

Tags: equations, classicthesis, breqn

I am using the `classicthesis` template.

I am trying to type the capital Greek letter Psi Ψ. However, it compiles as the symbol  ̄  . This stops when I disable `breqn`. This occurs in the regular equation mode with just

```
\[\Psi\]
```

but I have encountered this with `dmath` and `equation` as well.

Comment: Welcome! Please, add a minimal example of code that shows the issue.

Comment: Hello @egreg. I am having trouble trying to reproduce this issue on its own. Apologies for not including it. All I can tell for now is that `breqn` is clashing with something else but only using `breqn` isn't causing it.

EDIT: Upon downloading a fresh copy of `classicthesis`, I still have an error when I use `breqn` but I can't identify where it comes from.

Comment: Check the font packages

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with `\usepackage{fourier}`, which is definitely incompatible with `breqn`. Note that `classicthesis` has nothing to do with the issue. I'll never be tired of saying that `breqn` is a nice proof of concept, but it *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 2):

breqn documentation mentions the issue:

[image: breqn documentation]

[image: breqn documentation 2]

---

Normally you load the math font before `breqn`:

[image: documentation of special math font for breqn]

Unfortunately `fourier` is not one of the supported math fonts,
you need to figure out what's going on then create your own support file.

Similar question: [fourier - breqn corrupts fouriernc in TL 2016 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330012/breqn-corrupts-fouriernc-in-tl-2016)

The following is probably the proper way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage[fourier]{flexisym}  % it would suffice to do this if there were a `fourier.sym` support file
\usepackage{breqn}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_gset:cpx {mg@Greek}  {\hexnumber@\symotherletters}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
    \Psi
\]

\end{document}
```

Basically, you can

- read the existing support file (e.g. `mathpazo.sym`) to see what `breqn`/`flexisym` does with other math packages,
- read the source code of `fourier` package to figure out the ⟨sym-font⟩ name (`otherletters`),
- read around various source codes to figure out the little tricks that

  - LaTeX's `mathgroup` is TeX's `fam`,
  - `\mg@⟨flexisym internal symbol font name⟩` stores the `\mathgroup` number of that symbol font name,
  - `\sym⟨sym-font⟩` stores the mathgroup of that symbol font where `⟨sym-font⟩` is as in `fntguide`.

---

What if you load `breqn` before `fourier` instead?

You get some error messages on "commands already defined".

Internally, what's going on is that `fourier` runs `\DeclareMathSymbol` to redefine `\Psi` and many other commands, but the problem is

- `\DeclareMathSymbol` only allow safely redefining a control sequence if the meaning includes the string `mathchar`,
- `breqn`'s definition of `\Psi` does not have it,
- thus `\DeclareMathSymbol` raises an error and does not redefine the control sequence.

Is this LaTeX's fault or breqn's fault? I'm not sure, I can only trace the LaTeX code back to 2008 through GitHub log (https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/develop/base/ltfssdcl.dtx#L1591),
but breqn package is older than that. (Either way, TeX's lack of interface to check whether something is a math character forces LaTeX to use a string-in-meaning test which is fragile as you've seen)

Anyway, one way is to patch `\DeclareMathSymbol`: (you also need to similarly patch `\DeclareMathDelimiter` to avoid other error messages which is not done here):

```
\makeatletter
\def\originalDeclareMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\in@\csname sym#3\expandafter\endcsname
     \expandafter{\group@list}%
  \ifin@
    \begingroup
      \count\z@=#4\relax
      \count\tw@\count\z@
      \divide\count\z@\sixt@@n
      \count@\count\z@
      \multiply\count@\sixt@@n
      \advance\count\tw@-\count@
      \if\relax\noexpand#1% is command?
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Store the command name with a space attached inside
%    \cs{reserved@@b} in case we look at a robust definition.
%    \begin{macrocode}
        \edef\reserved@b{\expandafter\noexpand
                         \csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\space\endcsname}%
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Test both \verb=#1= and \verb*=#1 = for containing \texttt{mathchar}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
        \edef\reserved@a
          {\noexpand\in@{\expandafter\@gobble\string\mathchar}%
                        {\meaning#1\expandafter\meaning\reserved@b}}%
        \reserved@a
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Drop  \verb*=#1 = in case it was defined before.
%    \begin{macrocode}
        \global\expandafter\let\reserved@b\@undefined
        \ifin@
          \expandafter\set@mathsymbol
             \csname sym#3\endcsname#1#2%
             {\hexnumber@{\count\z@}\hexnumber@{\count\tw@}}%
          \@font@info{Redeclaring math symbol \string#1}%
        \else
          \expandafter\ifx
            \csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\endcsname
            \relax
            \expandafter\set@mathsymbol
               \csname sym#3\endcsname#1#2%
               {\hexnumber@{\count\z@}\hexnumber@{\count\tw@}}%
          \else
            \@latex@error{Command `\string#1' already defined}\@eha
          \fi
        \fi
      \else
        \expandafter\set@mathchar
          \csname sym#3\endcsname#1#2
          {\hexnumber@{\count\z@}\hexnumber@{\count\tw@}}%
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \else
    \@latex@error{Symbol font `#3' is not defined}\@eha
  \fi
}
\ifx\originalDeclareMathSymbol\DeclareMathSymbol \else \errmessage{Unexpected definition of DeclareMathSymbol!!}\fi
\def\DeclareMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\in@\csname sym#3\expandafter\endcsname
     \expandafter{\group@list}%
  \ifin@
    \begingroup
      \count\z@=#4\relax
      \count\tw@\count\z@
      \divide\count\z@\sixt@@n
      \count@\count\z@
      \multiply\count@\sixt@@n
      \advance\count\tw@-\count@
      \if\relax\noexpand#1% is command?
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Store the command name with a space attached inside
%    \cs{reserved@@b} in case we look at a robust definition.
%    \begin{macrocode}
        \edef\reserved@b{\expandafter\noexpand
                         \csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\space\endcsname}%
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Drop  \verb*=#1 = in case it was defined before.
%    \begin{macrocode}
        \global\expandafter\let\reserved@b\@undefined
        \expandafter\set@mathsymbol
           \csname sym#3\endcsname#1#2%
           {\hexnumber@{\count\z@}\hexnumber@{\count\tw@}}%
        \@font@info{Redeclaring math symbol \string#1}%
      \else
        \expandafter\set@mathchar
          \csname sym#3\endcsname#1#2
          {\hexnumber@{\count\z@}\hexnumber@{\count\tw@}}%
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \else
    \@latex@error{Symbol font `#3' is not defined}\@eha
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[paperheight=5cm, paperwidth=5cm]{geometry}
%\errorcontextlines=10
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}

\[
    \Psi
\]

\end{document}
```