# breqn package in beamer turns \Omega into a dot

Tags: beamer, fonts, breqn, fourier

I'm compiling a beamer presentation with the `fourier` font set, and the result shows a dot instead of the greek character `\Omega`. I have found that other people had the same problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336232/omega-in-lyx-shows-up-as-dot) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71111/dotx-and-beamer), but even after I put

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, fleqn]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

I still get the dot. I tried to get a MWE and then I realized that when commenting the line

```
\usepackage{breqn}
```

which is used to break long equations, the problem was solved. Do you know what's causing this behavior? Can it be fixed so I can still use the `breqn` package?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{breqn} % break equations

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Omega$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to be blunt but from a 10 year user with 3k reputation I expect a MWE. I'll be happy to retract the downvote when the question is edited.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667604/breqn-causes-tex-capacity-exceeded-when-using-neq-in-section-title#comment1659672_667604

Comment: Even after puzzling together a compilable mwe from your information, it works fine. No dot anywhere

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686447/82917 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330012/82917 Long story short: `breqn` isn't compatible with `fourier` (or `fouriernc`).

Comment: @campa I didn't add the MWE because it's shamefully simple—a user with an order of magnitude more reputation than me should have known... ;)

Comment: No, it's not shamefully simple. Sometimes bad interactions are hidden in a particular loading order, and no rep difference enables me to read minds. Anyway thanks for the edit, downvote converted to upvote.

Comment: @aaragon No, it is not shamefully simple, because a simple example works fine: ```\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, fleqn]{beamer}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[
  \Omega
  \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still my MWE doesn't, it seems the culprit is `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.

Comment: @aaragon ... and you said "even after I put..." which sounded as if you had the problem before you switched off beamer's font replacement. To avoid such confusing questions, you should always add a MWE, no matter how easy you think something is.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of doing “automatic” breaks in a presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to not use `breqn`, but it works fine if you don't disable beamer's font replacements:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{breqn} % break equations

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\Omega$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know of a proper alternative to the `breqn` package so breaking happens automatically?

Comment: @aaragon You'll get better results if you choose the breaking points yourself. In particular in such a visual medium as a presentation, you should carefully plan where to break your equations.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think you posted the wrong output image, [shouldn't it be this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzIXH.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :P